# Building Array of Objects in PHP

Tags: php

I am attempting to stitch together an array of objects from combining 2-3 arrays, shown here:

```
 while($j < $itemCounter && $i < $histCounter)
 {
     if($hists[$i]->itemid == $items[$j]->itemid)
     {
         //echo $i."\n";
         $doc[$i]->clock = intval($hists[$i]->clock); <-line 218
         $doc[$i]->value = floatval($hists[$i]->value);
         $doc[$i]->name = $items[$j]->name;
         $doc[$i]->hostname = $hostName[intval($items[$j]->hostid)];
         $i++;
     }
     else
     {
         //echo intval($hists[$i]->itemid) ."\t". intval($items[$j]->itemid)."\n";
         //echo $j."\n";
         if($hists[$i]->itemid > $items[$j]->itemid) $j++;
         else $i++;
     }
 }
```

And I keep getting a whole lot of these

> PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in **.php on line 218

I also get a lot of notice lines but .. I think fixing this issue may solve my problem.

Am I doing object building completely wrong? Do I need to build a class and object and structure this totally different?

This is my declaration for `$doc` at the moment:

```
$doc = NULL;
```

Comment: Please, provide some data to us, only for testing purpose, and what is the line 218?

Comment: Hey, I have highlighted in the code, line 218 is this guy $doc[$i]->clock = intval($hists[$i]->clock); Also, what sort of data could I provide you guys with ? I am pulling history items from zabbix and merging those items with itemGet and hostGet which give more information about what historic item I just pulled and what host the item is from. I need the data in one place so this is where I create the array of merged docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start setting the clock, initiate the object.

```
$doc[$i] = new stdClass();
```

Comment: Hey, it got rid of the warnings. Thanks friend!